# CASE WHEN GROUP BY Returning Duplicate values

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, case

I am using SQL Server 2012 and am trying to use a Case When Group By query.  The results give me duplicate values in the ProdType field.  I know this has to do with my Group by clause.  My query is:

```
    SELECT        


CASE WHEN dbo.tblPayCode.PayCode IN (10,11,12,13,14,15,16,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,30,31,32,33,34,35,36) THEN 'WORK'
     WHEN dbo.tblPayCode.PayCode > 39 AND dbo.tblPayCode.PayCode NOT IN (40,43,57,58,59,67,68,72,75,78,79) THEN 'SVLA'
END AS ProdType,

  dbo.tblJobsWorked.WrkDate, SUM(dbo.tblJobsWorked.Hours) AS TotalHours

FROM            dbo.tblEmployees INNER JOIN
                         dbo.tblJobsWorked ON dbo.tblEmployees.EMP_NUMB = dbo.tblJobsWorked.EMP_NUMB INNER JOIN
                         dbo.tblPayCode ON dbo.tblJobsWorked.PayCode = dbo.tblPayCode.PayCode INNER JOIN
                         dbo.tblCostCenters ON dbo.tblEmployees.CC_ORGN_NUMB = dbo.tblCostCenters.CC_C_NB AND 
                         dbo.tblEmployees.ORGN_DEPT_TYP_C = dbo.tblCostCenters.DEPT_TYP_C AND dbo.tblJobsWorked.CC_RSPB_NUMB = dbo.tblCostCenters.CC_C_NB AND 
                         dbo.tblJobsWorked.RSPB_DEPT_TYP_C = dbo.tblCostCenters.DEPT_TYP_C
GROUP BY 
dbo.tblPayCode.PayCode, dbo.tblJobsWorked.WrkDate 

HAVING     dbo.tblJobsWorked.WrkDate>'2013-04-30'

ORDER BY  dbo.tblJobsWorked.WrkDate
```

My results are

```
ProdType    WrkDate TotalHours
WORK    2013-05-01 00:00:00.000 58.70
WORK    2013-05-01 00:00:00.000 5.20
SVLA    2013-05-01 00:00:00.000 8.00
SVLA    2013-05-01 00:00:00.000 8.00
WORK    2013-05-01 00:00:00.000 68.00
WORK    2013-05-01 00:00:00.000 825.40
WORK    2013-05-01 00:00:00.000 8.90
SVLA    2013-05-01 00:00:00.000 21.00
SVLA    2013-05-01 00:00:00.000 8.00
SVLA    2013-05-01 00:00:00.000 8.00
WORK    2013-05-01 00:00:00.000 5.30
SVLA    2013-05-01 00:00:00.000 53.00
SVLA    2013-05-01 00:00:00.000 8.60
```

I am expecting to see 2 rows for 5/1/13 with 'WORK' and 'SVLA' and their total corresponding hours.  Your help is much appreciated!  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move that `HAVING` condition to `WHERE`

```
WHERE dbo.tblJobsWorked.WrkDate>'2013-04-30'
```

You should consider modifying your query like

```
SELECT ProdType, WrkDate, SUM(Hours) AS TotalHours FROM (
SELECT        
CASE WHEN dbo.tblPayCode.PayCode IN (10,11,12,13,14,15,16,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,30,31,32,33,34,35,36) THEN 'WORK'
     WHEN dbo.tblPayCode.PayCode > 39 AND dbo.tblPayCode.PayCode NOT IN (40,43,57,58,59,67,68,72,75,78,79) THEN 'SVLA'
END AS ProdType,
dbo.tblJobsWorked.WrkDate, 
dbo.tblJobsWorked.Hours

FROM            dbo.tblEmployees INNER JOIN
                         dbo.tblJobsWorked ON dbo.tblEmployees.EMP_NUMB = dbo.tblJobsWorked.EMP_NUMB INNER JOIN
                         dbo.tblPayCode ON dbo.tblJobsWorked.PayCode = dbo.tblPayCode.PayCode INNER JOIN
                         dbo.tblCostCenters ON dbo.tblEmployees.CC_ORGN_NUMB = dbo.tblCostCenters.CC_C_NB AND 
                         dbo.tblEmployees.ORGN_DEPT_TYP_C = dbo.tblCostCenters.DEPT_TYP_C AND dbo.tblJobsWorked.CC_RSPB_NUMB = dbo.tblCostCenters.CC_C_NB AND 
                         dbo.tblJobsWorked.RSPB_DEPT_TYP_C = dbo.tblCostCenters.DEPT_TYP_C

WHERE dbo.tblJobsWorked.WrkDate > '2013-04-30'
ORDER BY  dbo.tblJobsWorked.WrkDate ) xx

GROUP BY ProdType, WrkDate;
```

Comment: I made one tweak to this and it worked.  The ORDER BY clause had to be outside the sub-query.  Thanks for the help @Rahul

Answer (score 0):

The query first applies the grouping and only then applies the row-wise calculations in the select list. If you want these rows to be grouped together, you could apply the same `case` expression in the `group by` clause too.